# Throw an error in mule startup if property placeholders are missing in mule properties file?

Tags: java, mule

I have a several different sets of **mule-app.properties** files. My Mule flows make use of property placeholders, I noticed that should one of these properties be missing, mule will interpret the property placeholder as is. for example:

**${some.property}** will get interpreted as string **"${some.property}"**, should that property be missing in the properties file.

Is there a way to cause an error on compile/startup should any properties be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it should give a compile error. if not, try this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file.properties" ignore-unresolvable="false"/>
```

The placeholder with **ignore-unresolvable="false"**

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for, but how would I apply it to my default properties file (mule-app.properties)?

Comment: Try adding mule-app.properties as property-placeholder:  <context:property-placeholder location="mule-app.properties" />